# Mastermind algorithm but for unique colors only

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, probability, algorithm, mastermind

I have seen Donald Knuth's Algorithm to guess the correct pattern in maximum 5 tries. However, I want to write a program to find the correct pattern effectively however the code maker can only make a pattern with distinct colors. Donald's algorithm uses the fact that you can make a pattern with 2 or more same colors. Can someone help me find an algorithm that will guess the pattern effectively and not make random guesses?

Comment: Is the guesser also restricted to guesses unique colors? If not then you can use the algorithm unchanged and you will still be guaranteed to get it in 5.

Comment: @2012rcampion Yes, if the guesser tries to use a color more than once in his guess, he has  a penalty. the program wont even tell him if his pattern is partially correct or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by

> simply applying Knuth's algorithm as is, except limited to the patterns with no repetitions (6*5*4*3 = 360 out of 6^4 = 1296). You would only need to test one starting guess (they're all equivalent, just swap the colors around).

I don't know whether it would be optimal, but at least it would set a minimum.

Also note that optimizing for "requires N guesses at most" is different from optimizing for "requires N guesses on average". (Per Wikipedia, the optimal strategy for the latter has an average of just over 4.34, but a worst case of 6.)